# Android: strecthing background

Tags: android

I want to have a gradient on my app background. The picture is only ten pixels wide and I would like it to repeat horizontally. Then I have the background set to the color where the gradient ends vertically. In CSS I could easily do this by this code:

```
background: url("bg.png") repeat-x #0f0f0f;
```

But I have no idea how to do this on android. I tried setting a bitmap but everytime I put it in the XML the app force closes on me and there doesn't seem to be "repeat-x" like option on it.

So what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use bitmap shader to repeat a particular bitmap .
Refer to [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html)
Also check  [this Api Demo Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Patterns.html)